# Кодировка при отправке аякс

Tags: php, javascript

знач в браузере хром все ок, а в мозиле при отправке сообщения аяксом в базу заносит все в кривой кодировке, когда я в php поставил что бы перекодироваволо в win из utf тогда в хроме вообше не сохраняет а отправляет пустое поле, что делать?

Comment: [Юзаем поиск](http://hashcode.ru/search/?q=%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BA%D0%B0+ajax&t=question)

Answer (score 3):

AJAX-запрос в любом случае отправляет всё в UTF-8, даже если кодировка страницы не такая.

Сделай везде UTF-8 (в HTML, в JS, в PHP) и будет тебе счастье

Answer (score 1):

И про кодировку базы тоже не забываем)

Comment: Ну данные из базы можно и перекодировать в PHP, если база уже есть

Comment: **Я** знаю) я просто напоминаю ТС.